# MongoDB Aggregate $match between dates

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am attempting to aggregate documents that match a query. I'm using Mongoose with MongoDB.

```
    let today = new Date();
    let start = moment(today).startOf('year').toDate().toISOString();
    let end = moment(today).endOf('year').toDate().toISOString();
    let event_query = {"$gte" : start, "$lte" : end};

    console.log(event_query);
    /*
     *{ '$gte': '2019-01-01T08:00:00.000Z',
     *  '$lte': '2020-01-01T07:59:59.999Z' }
     */
    let promise = Model.aggregate([
        { $match: {"charged" : true, "createdAt": event_query}},
        { $group: { _id: "$customer",  total: { $sum: 1 } } }
     ]).exec();
```

I know this should match documents because when I use this query outside of an aggregate, it returns the expected documents.  Also, if I remove the `createdAt` query, this returns the expected query.

Why is my date query on the `createdAt` timestamp failing to match documents in an aggregate pipeline?

Comment: Remove`.toIsoString().`

Comment: @Fanpark Sigh...You're right. Thanks for your help!